# tinymce for Django is not loading - throwing error in init

Tags: django, django-tinymce

Here is my setup:

**urls.py**

```
....
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
....
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "theme_advanced_buttons1": ("formatselect,"
    "separator, bold, italic, "
    "underline, strikethrough, separator,"
    "justifyleft,justifycenter, justifyright,"
    "justifyfull, separator, bullist, numlist,"
    "separator, link, code")
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = False
TINYMCE_JS_URL = '/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = '/static/js/tiny_mce'
```

**my_template.html**

```
{% extends '_layout.html' %}

{% block extra_head %}
  {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class VenueForm(ModelForm):

    .....

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'description': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 10}),
        }
```

---

I've been searching through the documentation and other SO threads and I thought I had set it correctly. However, I'm getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: django is not defined


}(django.jQuery));
```

which is the last line in `static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js`.
All my resources are loading fine, no 404 error in the console
What am I missing? I've been struggling with this for the past two hours. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for I have to answer to my own question, is like giving a like on facebook to myself :)

But I found the solution and this might be helpful for other people.

I installed the latest version which is `django-tinymce==1.5.3`. This has a bug. I downgraded to `1.5.2` and everything went perfectly. Waiting for the bug to be fixed and looking forward to see `1.5.4`

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged with a badge: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner . You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This [workaround](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/issues/102#issuecomment-75445878) helped me out, without having to downgrade django-tinymce. You just have to define `django` on your template before `{{ form.media }}`:

```
<script>
  var django = {jQuery: jQuery};
</script>
{{ form.media }}
```

I hope this helps.